# How to upload multiple photos to Facebook from within iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, photos

Is there an API call that we can use to upload multiple photos to Facebook from iPhone app? So far we can do only one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the Facebook Connect API directly: the iOS SDK does not expose this kind of functionality.

You should have a look at the Publishing section of the [Graph Photo API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) which suggests this URL to upload an image (don't forget to ask for the `publish_stream` credential):

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos

message=[optional description]
source=[the image's data]
place=[optional image's location]
```

With the iOS Facebook Connect SDK that would give us this call, given you have a `Facebook` instance called `facebook` and a `UIImage` instance called `image`:

```
[facebook requestWithMethodName:@"/USER_ID/photos"
                      andParams:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7), @"source",
                                 @"My puppy is so cute!!!", @"message",
                                 nil]
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

You can couple this call with [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to upload multiple pictures simultaneously.

Comment: its share only single image.. need multiple images