# Can i share more than multiple images and multiple videos from iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I would like share multiple images and multiple videos in facebook from my app. How can i do that? Which one is better Social Framework or facebook SDK?

Answer (score -1):

use Facebook sdk if you want to share more than one image. please refer the link and read docs [facebook ios sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/)

Comment: I went through those but i didn't find solution to share multiple images at a time. Images and Videos are picking from the gallery of the device.

Comment: check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197414/how-to-upload-multiple-photos-to-facebook-from-within-iphone-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607473/ios-facebook-sdk-3-upload-image-with-message