# How to upload multiple photos on fb and twitter via iOS Social.framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I see only addImage: method in SLComposeViewController which takes single image.

Is there any way to attach an array of images to SLComposeViewController and share them in one go ?

Comment: SLComposeViewController has only addImage method means you can add only one image at a time and share.

Comment: I know it and I have mentioned that already in my question.

Comment: Please refer the below link for the same:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197414/how-to-upload-multiple-photos-to-facebook-from-within-iphone-app

Comment: for sharing multiple images you should to use Facebook iOS sdk

Comment: thanks, but the same solution from this link is already posted here by iDev.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the Facebook Connect API directly: the iOS SDK does not expose this kind of functionality.

You should have a look at the Publishing section of the Graph Photo API which suggests this URL to upload an image (don't forget to ask for the publish_stream credential):

```
    POST https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos

message=[optional description]
source=[the image's data]
place=[optional image's location]
With the iOS Facebook Connect SDK that would give us this call, given you have a Facebook instance called facebook and a UIImage instance called image:

[facebook requestWithMethodName:@"/USER_ID/photos"
                      andParams:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7), @"source",
                                 @"My puppy is so cute!!!", @"message",
                                 nil]
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Source Author:[ndfred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197414/how-to-upload-multiple-photos-to-facebook-from-within-iphone-app)

Comment: I get it. But I was looking for a way to do this via Social.framework only.

Answer (score 0):

Reference by [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SLRequest/addMultipartData%3awithName%3atype%3afilename%3a)

```
addMultipartData:withName:type:filename:
Specifies a named multipart POST body for this request.

- (void)addMultipartData:(NSData *)data withName:(NSString *)name type:(NSString*)type filename:(NSString *)filename
```

**Parameters**
**data**
The data for the multipart POST body, such as an image or text.
**name**
The name of the multipart POST body. This is the name that a specific social service expects.
**type**
The type of the multipart POST body. This is the MIME content type of the multipart data.
**filename**
The filename of the attachment that you want to POST. Many social services require a filename in order to accept certain POST requests, such as uploading an image or video. If your multipart data does not require a filename, pass in nil

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SLComposeViewController,I used UIActivityViewController to share multiple images on Facebook.also can share on Mail and other app as well.user must have social account configured on device.

```
NSString *message = @"initial Text";
UIImage *imageToShare =imageForShareOnMedia; //[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];

NSArray *postItems = @[message, imageToShare,imageToShare];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                            initWithActivityItems:postItems
                                            applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```